# Is there a better way to escape this string?

Tags: java, algorithm, coldfusion

What is the quickest way in ColdFusion (or Java) for converting a string as such:

```
Input:
79827349837493827498

Output:
\79\82\73\49\83\74\93\82\74\98
```

I'm taking an LDAP GUID and escaping it for a query.

I can do it as a series of MID reductions like this:

```
  <CFSET V1 = "">
  <CFSET RetVal = "">
  <CFLOOP CONDITION="#V1# NEQ''">
      <CFSET RetVal = RetVal & "\" & MID(V1,1,2)>
      <CFSET V1 = MID(V1,3,2000)>
  </CFLOOP>
```

But it seems like there would be something more elegant, like a regular expression replace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so the syntax might be off, but you should be able to do something like:

```
<cfset V1 = REReplace(V1,"([0-9]{2})","\\\1","all")>
```

Comment: thanks.  Exactly what I was looking for. I just realized my examples didn't have characters in it, but LDAP Guid does.  So the Regex ought to be closer to (\w{2}).

Answer (score 2):

In Java you could do

```
String text = text.replaceAll("(..)","\\\1");
```

Comment: Which is exactly what you could do in ColdFusion as well. But I believe it is: .replaceAll("(..)","\\$1") - Java back references work with a dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible way.

```
<cfset input = "79827349837493827498"/>
<cfset output = input/>

<cfloop from="#len(output)-2#" to="0" index="i" step="-2">
    <cfset output = insert("\",output,i)/>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#output#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: cool, I thought insert() wouldn't work, but looping down works! nice!

Comment: No, 'to' should be 0 because an insert() function position parameter of 0 prefixes the string.

Answer (score 0):

how about...

```
<cfset input = "79827349837493827490">
<cfset output = "">

<cfloop from="1" to="#len(input)#" index="count" step="2">
   <cfset output &= "\" & mid(input, count, 2)>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ColdFusion, but here's a simple Java approach:

```
private String injectBackslashes(String string) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length() / 2; ++i)
        sb.append('\\').append(string.substring(2*i, 2*i+2));
    return sb.toString();
}
```